# Excel check a range for multiple values

Tags: vba, excel

I've scoured Google for some assistance with this Excel problem but to no avail.

I have four input cells A1:A4 and one output cell A5. If cell A1 contains the word "red" I want the output cell to be modified from "No" (or blank) to "Yes". If cells A2:A4 contain the words "green" or "blue", I want the output cell A5 to be modified from "No" (or blank) to "Yes". If the contents of cells A1:A4 change to any other value or are blank I want the output cell A5 to be changed back to blank or "No".

Once completed, the solution will be copied down a number of further rows so I need it to dynamically update either when it copies or when it executes to ensure it is referencing in the correct row.

So far I have the following formula embedded in Cell A5 and it is working fine.

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Red",$A1:$A1,0)),"Yes","No")

I am struggling to incorporate the conditions I need for cells A2:A4.

I've tried conditional formatting, VBA modules, and formulae directly embedded in the cells but am not having much luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-Michael

Comment: Here's a rather ugly formula that should get you started: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Red",$A1:$A1,0)),"Yes",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A4,"green")>0,"Yes",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A4,"blue")>0,"Yes","No")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the answer provided by Portland Runner:

=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH("Red",$A1:$A1,0)),"Yes",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A4,"green")>0,"Yes",IF‌​(COUNTIF(A2:A4,"blue")>0,"Yes","No")))

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UDF that will work for your specific situation. Copy this code to a module and input "=RngVal()" into A5 and it will populate with "Yes" or "No" based on your criteria.

```
Function RngVal() as String
Dim flg as Boolean
Dim c as Range
If Range("A1") = "red" Then
RngVal = "Yes"
Else
For Each c in Range("A2:A4")
   If c = "blue" or c = "green" Then
   flg = true
   Exit For
   End If
Next c
If flg = True
RngVal = "Yes"
Else
RngVal = "No"
End If
End Function
```